# Plotly - draw background shapes on radar plot

Tags: python, plotly

With the following function:

```
def plot_radar_analysis(df_team_matches, team=None, gameweek=None, kip=None):

  from math import pi
  import plotly.express as px
  from colors import full_team_colors

  gameweeks=range(1,gameweek+1)

  df_temp = df_team_matches.loc[(df_team_matches['ForTeam']==team[0])
                                &(df_team_matches['GameWeek'].isin(gameweeks))]

  indicator = df_temp[kip[0]]

  R = list(indicator.values)
  theta = [('Rodada ' + str(i)) for i in list(df_temp['GameWeek'].values)]

  color = full_team_colors[team[0]]

  df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=R,
    theta=theta))

  fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True, title=f'{team[0]} - {kip[0]}')
  fig.update_polars(angularaxis_type="category") 
  fig.update_traces(fill='toself', line_color=color)
  fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

  return fig
```

I plot this:

[image]

---

No I would like to add style to my radar plot, and add some low opacity shapes to  my main figure in order to have the background look like this:

[image]

Please mind that football-related shapes should remain at background, and that the red area will go on top of those.

---

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can draw these shapes and achieve a result that resembles the image above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way to do this, but here is what I found.

#### Making polar grid transparent

- Make the background color of the grid transparent by adding `bgcolor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"` argument to your `fig.update_polars` call. (last zero is the important, other values don't matter)

```py
    fig.update_polars(angularaxis_type="category",
                      bgcolor="rgba(223, 223, 223, 0)")
```

#### Adding image to background

- Use [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create image object from a file on your hard disk
- Add image with

```py
from PIL import Image

fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(source=Image.open('bg_football.jpg'),
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            x=0.5,
            y=0.5,
            sizex=1,
            sizey=1,
            sizing="contain",
            xanchor="center",
            yanchor="middle",
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below"))
```

https://plotly.com/python/images/

- The `xref='paper'` and `yref='paper'` make the image to be positioned with respect to paper. If `xref='x'` and `yref='y'`, then the image is positioned with a cartesian coordinate axes. I did not find a possibility to position the image with respect to polar coordinates.
- The `x=0.5, y=0.5, xanchor='center', yanchor='middle'` makes the image to be centered.
- The `sizing="contain"` keeps the image size as-is. Other possible values are  "contain" and "stretch".
- `source` can be URL string or `PIL.Image` instance.

### The resulting figure

[image: results]

### Notes

- In case you need to tweak the CSS to make the image be the same size as the plot in every situation & screen size etc.: The image will be placed in the DOM inside a `<g class=layer-below>`, which is different from the `<g>`-element with your polar plot (`<g class=polarlayer>`) and they have a common parent `<svg class=main-svg>`, which has parent `<div class=svg-container>`.

#### Additional resources

- [Plotly image reference](https://plotly.com/python/images/)
- [plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_layout_image](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_layout_image)

Comment: thanks a lot for the very complete and useful answer.